# Put focus on number input field and then simulate arrow keypress

Tags: jquery

I have a Button which, when clicked, should focus on an input field next to it and then simulate the 'Up arrow' key press. This should increment the value inside the input field. I've written the following code but it does not seem to be working:

```
$('.add').click(function () {

        var selectedInput = $(this).prev('input');

            if (selectedInput.val() < 10) {
                    selectedInput.focus();
                    selectedInput.trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 38 }));
            }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use HTML element functions,
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_number_stepup.asp

```js
$(document).on('click','.add', function () {

        var selectedInput = $('.product-quantity input');

            if (selectedInput.val() < 10) {
                    selectedInput.focus();
                    selectedInput[0].stepUp(1);
            }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="product-quantity"> <input type="number"  value="0"/>
<span class="add">Add</span>
</div>
```

Comment: From reading the documentation which you attached it seems like this is exactly what I need, however the example you provided just does not seem to work for me. Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: your selectors might have some problem.. can you provide the non working snippet

Comment: here is the snippet:
'    //Add +/- buttons to input
 $('<span class="add" uk-icon="plus"></span>').insertAfter('.product-cotainer .product-quantity input');
 $('<span class="sub" uk-icon="minus"></span>').insertBefore('.product-cotainer .product-quantity input'); 
 
 
 
 //Add functinoality to + button 
 $('.add').click(function () {
 
  var selectedInput = $(this).prev('input');
  
   if (selectedInput.val() < 10) {
     selectedInput.focus();
     selectedInput[0].stepUp(1);
   }
   
 });
'

Comment: I also get the following error in the console:
"InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"

Comment: that is not at all related to the above code! you might be using some media elements like video etc..

Comment: the console says that error is reffered to this line of code: selectedInput[0].stepUp(1);

Comment: ``` 
selectedInput.get(0).stepUp(1);
```

Comment: still having the same issue I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this
In your .cshtml

```
 <input type=button id=abc value="abc">
 <input type="text" id="txtABC" value=1>
```

and in your javascript
instead of up key arrow event you can directly set value into textbox like this

```
$("#abc").on('click',function(){
$("#txtABC").focus();
$("#txtABC").val(+$("#txtABC").val()+1);
//alert('hi')
})
```

I have added small sample over here.
Refer it for

https://jsbin.com/cotinexore/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I have tried this method before but unfortunatelly because I'm using a third party system, incrementing the value like this does not work with another field which works out a mathematical equation from this field. 
The only way I can get it to work is by simulating a keypress to increment the value